# Replace 'GET' url with a variable

Tags: json, url, replace

I've searched for this topic and ended here https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=api+replace+%27GET%27+url+with+a+variable yet no answer seems to address my question.

This is my code:

```
function wpp(){
let ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
ourRequest.open('GET', 'https://averylong.url/with/some/stuff/andshit'); <-- wan to to replace this with a variable
ourRequest.onload = function() {
  if (ourRequest.status >= 200 && ourRequest.status < 400) {
    let data = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
    myHtml(data);    
  } else {
    console.log("server returned an error.");
  }
};
ourRequest.onerror = function() {
  console.log("Connection error");
};
ourRequest.send();
}
```

what I want to do is the following:

```
let myNewUrl = localStorage.getItem(449);
function wpp(){
    let ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ourRequest.open('GET', myNewUrl);
    ourRequest.onload = function() {
      if (ourRequest.status >= 200 && ourRequest.status < 400) {
        let data = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
        myHtml(data);    
      } else {
        console.log("server returned an error.");
      }
    };
    ourRequest.onerror = function() {
      console.log("Connection error");
    };
    ourRequest.send();
 }
```

But every time I get this error:

> GET https://averylong.url/with/some/stuff/449 403 (Forbidden)

but if I copy/paste the very same URL in my browser I get back the JSON data no problem.

EDIT screenshot

[image: console error]

Comment: Does the URL work in Postman?

Comment: what is the exact error in the console?

Comment: @samgak Yes it does

Comment: @DanielGee literally this one:
GET https://averylong.url/with/some/stuff/449 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: not sure i can help. i can't access the website

Comment: might be something to do with the fact you are using xhr. some services block these requests

Comment: Did you compare the headers? 
When the xhr is happenning, go to your network tab and go to the request and check the request of the headers. 
When you are calling postman, try to duplicate the headers that you see of chrome, remove one by one in postman and see if you find an issue.
Replacing a variable in the for an url is not your question.

Comment: @ravi this is a very good hint Let me dig in to it and will let you all know whatever I find

Comment: @ravi Thank You I found the answer thanks to your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to thank @ravi his comment lead me way down in to the rabbit hole..... Some things can not being unseen, but I found the answer somewhere.

The problem was ModSecurity it happends that ModSecurity does not like wordpress and you have to disable it or it will return a 403 error, now the funny part is that even when it return a 403 error it will display the results on the 'browser' and 'Postman' and that is why I tought I was writing wrong javascript, it happends that when javascript finds the 403 error just stops and wont render the answer even if it's there. Solution: turn off ModSecurity if you are working with wordpress API.